# How does the iphone camera display graphics?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, camera

I was curious to know how the iphone/ipad/ipod camera show the display screen i.e. once we open up the camera app, how does the app show up the graphics on the display ? How does it paint the content on the display layer/surface? Does it use the GPU for that ?

Any Links on the same would be very useful.

Thanks.

Comment: Route of data: camera chip -> driver -> kernel -> userland camera app -> kernel -> other driver -> framebuffer -> GPU -> physical display.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So, the framebuffer contents in the camera app are transferred/painted to the default surface of the display? If not (which is what I suppose), then what happens ? Also, can you expand on your answer.